# Pig: How to join data on a key in a nested bag

Tags: apache-pig

I'm simply trying to merge in the values from `data2` to `data1` on the `'value1'/'value2'` keys seen in both `data1` and `data2` (note the nested structure of

Easy right? In object oriented code it's a nested for loop. But in Pig it feels like solving a rubix cube.

```
data1 = 'item1'     111     { ('thing1', 222, {('value1'),('value2')}) }
data2 = 'value1'    'result1'
        'value2'    'result2'

A = load 'data6' as ( item:chararray, d:int, things:bag{(thing:chararray, d1:int, values:bag{(v:chararray)})} );
B = load 'data7' as ( v:chararray, r:chararray );

expected: 'item1', 111, {('thing1', 222, {('value1','result1'), ('value2','result2')})}
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For the curious: data1 comes from an object oriented datastore, which explains the double nesting (simple object oriented format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you basically just want to do a join (unclear from the question if this should be INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, or FULL. I think @SNeumann basically has the write answer, but I'll add some code to make it clearer.

Assuming the data looks like:

```
data1 = 'item1'     111     { ('thing1', 222, {('value1'),('value2')}) }
        ...
data2 = 'value1'    'result1'
        'value2'    'result2'
        ...
```

I'd do something like (**untested**):

```
A = load 'data6' as ( item:chararray, d:int, things:bag{(thing:chararray, d1:int, values:bag{(v:chararray)})} );
B = load 'data7' as ( v:chararray, r:chararray );
A_flattened = FOREACH A GENERATE item, d, things.thing AS thing; things.d1 AS d1, FLATTEN(things.values) AS value;
--This looks like:
--'item1', 111, 'thing1', 222, 'value1'
--'item1', 111, 'thing1', 222, 'value2'
A_B_joined = JOIN A_flattened BY value, B BY v;
--This looks like:
--'item1', 111, 'thing1', 222, 'value1', 'value1', 'result1'
--'item1', 111, 'thing1', 222, 'value1', 'value2', 'result2'
A_B_joined1 = FOREACH A_B_JOINED GENERATE item, d, thing, d1, A_flattened::value AS value, r AS result;
A_B_grouped = GROUP A_B_joined1 BY (value, result);
```

From there, rebagging however you like should be trivial.

**EDIT**: The above should have used '.' as the projection operator on tuples. I've switched that in. It also assumed `things` was a big tuple, which it isn't. It's a bag of one item. If the OP never plans to have more than one item in that bag, I'd highly recommend using a tuple instead and loading as:

```
A = load 'data1' as (item:chararray, d:int, things:(thing:chararray, d1:int, values:bag{(v:chararray)}));
```

and then using the rest of the code essentially as is (**note: still untested**).

If a bag is absolutely required, then the entire problem changes, and it becomes unclear what the OP wants to happen when there are multiple `things` objects in the bag. Bag projection is also quite a bit more complicated as noted [here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/intro_pig_latin.html)

Comment: This is extremely helpful, where you flatten 'things::values' we were attempting, unsuccessfully, to flatten(things.values) and thought that was impossible. I see that you can reference into a bag using ::, no the '.' operator. Thank you very much for the code example, it helps us a lot.

Comment: I'm confused about the '::' usage. I got errors trying to use it, and I posted another question, on which the answer suggested I use '.' notation, not '::'. I'm trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: If I try the first line for A_flattened (using '.', not '::') I get this output, which I don't understand: A_flattened: {item: chararray,d: int,thing: {(thing: chararray)},d1: {(d1: int)},value: {(v: chararray)}}

Comment: The '.' notation is correct. Like I said, my script was untested. Just wanted to give you the basic idea.

The reason you're running into the strange projections is that `things` is a bag, so any projection on it will also result in a bag. I've edited my answer with a bit more info.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to flatten the bag in A that contains values (1,2), join with B (inner, outer, whatever you're after) and then group again and project the desired structure using TOBAG, etc.

Comment: I'll give it another whirl, as I tried to re-group 2 levels up the whole thing felt like a rubix cube to solve. I didn't play with TOBAG and am not very familiar with it, so I'll read up, maybe that was the key I was missing.