# Pig: What is the correct syntax to flatten a nested bag (2-levels deep)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm loading this data:

```
data6 = 'item1' 111 { ('thing1', 222, {('value1'),('value2')}) }
```

Using this command

```
A = load 'data6' as ( item:chararray, d:int, things:bag{(thing:chararray, d1:int, values:bag{(v:chararray)})} );
```

I'm attempting to flatten the whole thing this command.

```
A_flattened = FOREACH A GENERATE item, d, things::thing AS thing; things::d1 AS d1, FLATTEN(things::values) AS value;
```

But I just get this error:

```
Invalid field projection. Projected field [things::thing] does not exist in schema: item:chararray,d:int,things:bag{:tuple(thing:chararray,d1:int,values:bag{:tuple(v:chararray)})}
```

I tried naming the inner `things` tuple, but I get a similar error. Can someone help me with the right syntax here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **things.thing**, **things.d1**, **thangs.values**, as you want to do the projection on bag. The **#** is used by the projection on **map**.

Here is an introduction of **Bag projection** (search "Bag projection" in this page): http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/intro_pig_latin.html

**::** is used to avoid the name conflict when you **join** some inputs with the same field names. **join** preserves the names of the fields of the inputs passed to it. It also prepends the name of the relation the field came from, followed by a **::**. For example,

```
-- join2key.pig
daily = load 'NYSE_daily' as (exchange, symbol, date, open, high, low, close,
            volume, adj_close);
divs  = load 'NYSE_dividends' as (exchange, symbol, date, dividends);
jnd   = join daily by (symbol, date), divs by (symbol, date);
```

The description of **jnd** is:

```
jnd: {daily::exchange: bytearray,daily::symbol: bytearray,daily::date: bytearray,
daily::open: bytearray,daily::high: bytearray,daily::low: bytearray,
daily::close: bytearray,daily::volume: bytearray,daily::adj_close: bytearray,
divs::exchange: bytearray,divs::symbol: bytearray,divs::date: bytearray,
divs::dividends: bytearray}
```

The **daily::** prefix does not need to be used unless the field name is no longer unique in the record. In this example, you will need to use **daily::date** or **divs::date** if you wish to refer to one of the **date** fields after the join. But fields such as **open** and **divs** you do not, because there is no ambiguity.

Comment: What is '::' used for? I'm trying to follow the answer to this question that suggests its use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711420/pig-how-to-join-data-on-a-key-in-a-nested-bag